# Refactor repetitive query on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can't wrap my head around this, what's the best way to refactor this?

```
private function generateUsername($first, $last)
    {
        $un1 = Str::lower($first . $last);
        $un2 = Str::lower($first . '.' . $last);
        $un3 = Str::lower($first . '-' . $last);
        $un4 = Str::lower($first . '_' . $last);

        if (!User::where('username', $un1)->first()) {
            return $un1;
        } elseif (!User::where('username', $un2)->first()) {
            return $un2;
        } elseif (!User::where('username', $un3)->first()) {
            return $un3;
        } elseif (!User::where('username', $un4)->first()) {
            return $un4;
        } else {
            return $un1 . rand(1, 9);
        }
    }
```

seems very repetitive, any way i can just have one line function to look if the username already exists? it's not for validation, i want to automatically generate their username based on their full name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor something like this:

```
private function generateUsername($first, $last)
{
    $separators = ['', '.'. '-', '_'];

    foreach($separators as $separator) {
       $un = Str::lower($first . $separator . $last);
       if(!User::where('username', $un)->first()) return un;
    }

    return $un1 . rand(1, 9);
    
}
```

Comment: never thought you can use if statement like that (without brackets)